# php code printing on 2 pages instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have build a POS system on php and facing one very funny issue. I can add upto 20 items on the sale memo and it gets stored in the db and we can retrieve it and print it, but whenever I print it, it always comes out in 2 pages instead of one even if there's one item and the rest of the value is null. Is there a way to force print on one page?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Print Invoice - Chara Motor Servicing</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="text-center">

                <h3>Chara Motor Servicing</h3>
                <h4>Address Line 1</h4>
                <h4>Telephone: 000000000000</h4>
                <h4>GSTIN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h4>
            </div>
            <hr>
<?php
    include 'database_connection.php';
    $data=$_GET['invoice_id'];
    $user_id=$data;

    $sql = "SELECT `name`, `phone`, `town`, `date`, `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, `item4`, `item5`, `item6`, `item7`, `item8`,`item9`, `item10`, `item11`, `item12`, `item13`, `item14`, `item15`, `item16`,`item17`, `item18`, `item19`, `item20`, `item21`, `item22`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`, `q6`, `q7`, `q8`,`q9`, `q10`, `q11`, `q12`, `q13`, `q14`, `q15`, `q16`,`q17`, `q18`, `q19`, `q20`, `q21`, `q22`, `taxper`, `amt1`, `amt2`, `amt3`, `amt4`, `amt5`, `amt6`, `amt7`, `amt8`, `amt9`, `amt10`, `amt11`, `amt12`, `amt13`, `amt14`, `amt15`, `amt16`,`amt17`, `amt18`, `amt19`, `amt20`, `amt21`, `amt22`,`taxtotal`, `subtotal`, `status` FROM `sales` WHERE id=$user_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        ?>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-left">
                    <div class="panel panel-default height">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Invoiced To: </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <strong><?php echo $row['name']; ?></strong><br>
                            <?php echo $row['phone']; ?><br>
                            <?php echo $row['town']; ?><br>
                            <?php echo $row['date']; ?><br>
                            <strong>Invoice#: <?php echo $user_id; ?><br> </strong>
                            <strong><?php echo $row['status']; ?><br> </strong><br>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary hidden-print" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span> Print</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Order Summary</strong></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Item Name</strong></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><strong>Item Quantity</strong></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><strong>Total Price</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item1']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q1']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt1']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item2']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q2']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt2']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item3']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q3']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt3']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item4']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q4']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt4']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item5']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q5']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt5']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item6']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q6']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt6']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item7']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q7']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt7']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item8']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q8']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt8']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item9']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q9']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt9']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item10']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q10']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt10']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item11']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q11']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt11']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item12']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q12']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt12']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item13']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q13']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt13']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item14']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q14']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt14']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item15']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q15']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt15']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item16']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q16']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt16']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item17']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q17']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt17']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item18']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q18']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt18']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item19']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q19']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt19']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item20']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q20']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt20']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item21']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q21']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt21']; ?></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['item22']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row['q22']; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $row['amt22']; ?></td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="highrow"></td>
                                    <td class="highrow"></td>
                                    <td class="highrow text-center"><strong>GST/Tax (%)</strong></td>
                                    <td class="highrow text-right"><?php echo $row['taxper']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="emptyrow"></td>
                                    <td class="emptyrow"></td>
                                    <td class="emptyrow text-center"><strong>GST/Tax Amount</strong></td>
                                    <td class="emptyrow text-right"><?php echo $row['taxtotal']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                    <td class="emptyrow"></td>
                                    <td class="emptyrow text-center"><strong>SubTotal</strong></td>
                                    <td class="emptyrow text-right"><strong><?php echo $row['subtotal']; ?></strong></td>

                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

<style>
.height {
    min-height: 200px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 47px;
    color: #5CB85C;
}

.iconbig {
    font-size: 77px;
    color: #5CB85C;
}

.table > tbody > tr > .emptyrow {
    border-top: none;
}

.table > thead > tr > .emptyrow {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.table > tbody > tr > .highrow {
    border-top: 3px solid;
}
</style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using default print of the browser ?

Comment: Can you share the results of select query? Just a screen shot?

Comment: You should help others by posting only the relevant code - which is the **generated** markup in your case. PHP and MySQL are not involved after all, as they are not connected to printing anything

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, your page appears to be hard-coded to show 22 rows in the table, regardless of how many data items actually exist. I suggest instead using a PHP loop to loop through the list and only echo a HTML row for items which actually contain data.

Comment: However I suspect part of the reason you've hard-coded this is because you've hard-coded a 22 item list into the structure of your database table. This is a bad design, because if someone ever wants more items then you have to amend all your tables and queries and code pages which deal with it. And as you've seen it's a problem when there are sometimes less items, because you have to write extra code to cope with that.

Comment: A more conventional, normalised database design would have a "salesItems" table as a child table of the "sales" table, with the sale ID as a foreign key back to the sales table. Each row in salesItems would be one item containing the item ID, amount and price. That would mean if you want to get all the items for a particular sale, you can just SELECT them from salesItems (restricting by sale ID of course), and then loop through the returned results and print them out. No matter if there are 0, 1, 10, or 22 items the code would be identical and it would always print exactly the correct number

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI : yes I am using the default print browser.

Comment: Plus this is not even producing proper HTML in its current form, inside of your loop you are basically outputting `<div class="row">[…]</div> </div> </div> <div class="row">[…]</div></div>`

Comment: @cha Like running the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: What is the best solution for this ? @ADyson

Comment: The best solution is re-designing you database with a salesItems table, as I've suggested. Study the topic of relational database design and database normalisation so that you understand how to structure your data in the correct way. When you've done that, you'll find the rest of the solution suddenly becomes much simpler - it's then easy for PHP to select the items for the sale, and run a loop to print out each item it finds. If it finds one item returned by the query, it prints 1 item, if it finds 22 items it prints them all, but the code to do that is identical in either case.

Comment: As I mentioned, you should study database design before you continue, but here is a general bit of advice on that for the specific situation you've got here: If ever you find yourself adding more columns in your table to contain a new copy of the same thing (like where you have amt, qty, item columns 22 times in this case) then that's a warning to you that your design is wrong and you need a second table,

Comment: Thank you @ADyson I will try doing that. Meanwhile this is the screenshot of the print page once I click on print. https://gyazo.com/7d2bbc7c404e639b0704da5a2e239001

Comment: Yes, that's because you've hard-coded 22 `<tr>`s into your table, which will be displayed regardless of whether they contain any data or not. Using a loop to echo only rows which are actually needed will solve it.